# Recommended MySQL INDEX for storing domain names

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm trying to store about 100 Million domain names in a MySQL database, but I can't figure out the right INDEX method to use on the domain names.

The issue being that *LIKE* queries will also be executed:

```
SELECT id FROM domains WHERE domain LIKE '%.example.com'
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM domains WHERE domain LIKE 'example.%'
```

If it makes it easier, '%example%' is not a requirement, but at best a nice to have / be able to.

What would be the proper index to use? Left to right (example.%) should be realitivly straight forward, but right to left (%.example.com) is problematic but the most common query.

I'm using MariaDB 10.3 on Linux. DB running on a PCI-e SSD, lookup times longer then 10 seconds should be coincided "unacceptable"

Comment: Try to add teh index and see ,if it helps, you can always remove  it again , if it doesn't work at all. You also should tale a look add FULLTEXT_iNDEXES and see how they work, but as always you can remove it again.

Comment: spend one virtual permanent column (rdomain) in your table where the virtual function stores the domainname in reverse order like REVERSE(domain). so it is possible to search from start of string i.e. search for '%.mydomain.com' -> WHERE rdomain like REVERSE('%.mydomain.com')

Comment: @BerndBuffen Please submit this as an answer, this worked excellent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spend one virtual permanent column (rdomain) in your table where the virtual function stores the domainname in reverse order like **REVERSE(domain).** so it is possible to search from start of string i.e. search for '%.mydomain.com' -> WHERE rdomain like REVERSE('%.mydomain.com

**the table**

```
CREATE TABLE `myreverse` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_domain` (`domain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**add the column**

```
ALTER TABLE myreverse
ADD COLUMN rdomain VARCHAR(64) AS  (REVERSE(domain)),
ADD KEY idx_rdomain (rdomain);
```

**insert some data**

```
INSERT INTO `myreverse` (`id`, `domain`)
VALUES
    (2, 'img.google.com'),
    (3, 'w3.google.com'),
    (1, 'www.coogle.com'),
    (4, 'www.google.de'),
    (5, 'www.mydomain.com');
```

**see the data**

```
mysql> SELECT * from myreverse;
+----+------------------+------------------+
| id | domain           | rdomain          |
+----+------------------+------------------+
|  1 | www.google.com   | moc.elgoog.www   |
|  2 | img.google.com   | moc.elgoog.gmi   |
|  3 | w3.coogle.com    | moc.elgooc.3w    |
|  4 | www.google.de    | ed.elgoog.www    |
|  5 | www.mydomain.com | moc.niamodym.www |
+----+------------------+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

now you can query with reverse order and MySQL can use the index.

**query**

```
mysql> select * from myreverse WHERE rdomain like REVERSE('%.google.com');
+----+----------------+----------------+
| id | domain         | rdomain        |
+----+----------------+----------------+
|  3 | w3.google.com  | moc.elgoog.3w  |
|  2 | img.google.com | moc.elgoog.gmi |
+----+----------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here you can see that the optimizer use the index.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select * from myreverse WHERE rdomain like REVERSE('%.google.com');
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | myreverse | NULL       | range | idx_rdomain   | idx_rdomain | 195     | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure an index would help you here. If you can't change the database, your options seem limited. One thing you could do, is if you're running both a subdomain and domain query back to back, to run the subdomain query first. That should help reduce the number of rows the domain query has to cover.

It would definitely help if you split the URL between subdomains and domains into different columsn in the database. Have indexes for both of them. Then you could query the subdomains only and the domains only. It should speed things up. And if there are a lot of repeating values, you should normalize those fields so to remove repetition and speed up queries even more.